# jquery click on button display specific template

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, button, html-table

**Problem**
[image]

I am facing an issue in javascript, i want to do if user click on `send button` they show that template name a/c to table

**For example:** if user click on `send button` then display template name `checked`.

what should i do? Anyone help me?

My code here:

```
                $(document).on("click", "#send", function (e){
                    
                    var tempname = $(this).closest("tr").find("td.name").text();       //template data
                    var tempbody = $(this).closest("tr").find("td.body").text();   

                    console.log("tempname",tempname);
                    console.log("tempbody",tempbody);
                }
            });


            <tr class="template_lists" scope="row">
                <td style="display:none" class="index" ></td>
                <td class="name"></td>
                <td class="body" hidden></td>
                <td>
                <button type="button" id="send" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</td>
```

**expected output**
[image]

Comment: if  all buttons with same id  the first one will be triggered  may if you use class instead of id it should work

Comment: Can you update the question with the HTML part please.

Comment: i try ..i use class instead of id but it not working [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4399730/moufed)

Comment: alright [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8179526/adin-sijamija)

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
$(document).on("click", "#send", function (e){
          $(this).closest("tr").find("td.name").html('checked');
                }
            });
```

I can't really understand what you mean. If I was wrong, you can comment on me~

Comment: thanks it it not working [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13927642/yanyusanqian)

Comment: `Issue` if all buttons with same id the first one will be triggered may if you use class instead of id it should work [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13927642/yanyusanqian)

Comment: sorry, I forgot delete the `var tempname = `. Try this : `$(this).closest("tr").find("td.name").html('checked');`